# Использование в MYSQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c условием

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO product (user_id,..., prod_count)
VALUES (692,'...,2),(692,...,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dish_count = dish_count+1
```

Требуется чтобы при наличии дубликатов кол-во увеличивалось не на 1, а на то, что пришло в переменных в разделе VALUES(например product.prod_count + 2).

Возможно ли сделать это средствами MYSQL или все же  придется делать несколько запросов(определение наличия, а потом вставка или обновление).
Даже нормально запрос не пойму как составить. Буду рад любой помощи, даже если она выльется лишь в ссылку на наметки решения )))

Comment: `dish_count = dish_count+values(prod_count)`, например. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Золотой Вы человек. Цены Вам нет. В общем огромное спасибо!!!